# Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when I added the google sdk

Tags: android, sdk, google-api, dalvik

I looked up the error and found other people having the same problem, and tried almsot everything I could. Removing the android.jar from the build path and cleaning did not work, editing the proguard did not work, removing everything besides the android x.x.x and then cleaning did not work. The only thing I found that could be the problem was that I messed up somehow while adding the google libs. Here's all the relevant images of my workspace:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/crpPM.jpg

The only thing I noticed is my libs and android private libraries are minimally different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added android.jar into your libs folder ? then remove it from there also after removing it from build path and try compiling it again.